# Why does $\sqrt{8^2+(8\sqrt 3)^2}=16$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

The first step is take out $8^2$, then $8\sqrt{ (8\sqrt{3})^2 }$.

What are the correct next steps?

Comment: Check: $\sqrt{8^2+(8\sqrt3)^2} = 8\sqrt{1+3}$

Comment: When you "took out" the $8^2$ the sum in the root went missing. Where did it go?

Answer (score 10):

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{n}&:=\sqrt{8^2+(8\sqrt{3})^2}\\
\\
&=\sqrt{64+(8\sqrt{3})^2}\\
\\
&=\sqrt{64+8^2\cdot\left(\sqrt{3}\right)^2}\\
\\
&=\sqrt{64+64\cdot 3}\\
\\
&=\sqrt{64+192}\\
\\
&=\sqrt{256}\\
\\
&=\sqrt{16^2}\\
\\
&=16
\end{split}\tag1
\end{equation}

Answer (score 4):

Alternative to Jan Eerland his answer:

\begin{align}
\sqrt{8^2 + (8\sqrt{3})^2} = \sqrt{8^2 + 8^2 (\sqrt{3})^2} = \sqrt{8^2 + 8^2 \cdot 3} = \sqrt{8^2(1 + 3)} = \sqrt{8^2 \cdot 2^2} = 8 \cdot 2 = 16.
\end{align}